# udhcpd instance reports address already in use

Tags: dhcp, raspberry-pi, ip-address, dhcp-server, hostapd

I am attempting to setup a dhcp server, using udhcpd as the dhcp server.

**Background info:**

Following a tutorials for configuring a dhcp server (for Raspberry Pi AP's e.g. [here](http://xmodulo.com/raspberry-pi-wifi-access-point.html) and [here](http://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Wireless_AP_with_udhcpd_and_NAT) and [here](http://elinux.org/RPI-Wireless-Hotspot)), I get stuck with the `udhcpd` server. Note with the links that all use the same `udhcp` server, where mine is configured identically to those specified, yet I am presented with this error on boot

**Problem:**

```
# sudo udhcpd -f
udhcpd (v1.22.1) started
udhcpd: bind: Address already in use
```

This was run from the console, but the same message(s) are found in the `syslog`

At the time of the above command, no DHCP instance was running, this was confirmed with `sudo ps -aux | grep dhcp`.

```
# sudo ps -aux | grep dhcp
admin     3375  0.0  0.2   4280  1892 pts/2    S+   22:50   0:00 grep --color=auto dhcp
```

**Extra Info:**

The NIC used for the dhcp is `wlan1`.

/etc/network/interfaces

```
//...

iface wlan1 inet static
    address 192.168.2.254
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.8.254 #internet-facing NIC
    network 192.168.2.0
    broadcast 192.168.2.255

//...
```

udhcpd.conf

```
start           192.168.2.1    #default: 192.168.0.20
end             192.168.2.240   #default: 192.168.0.254

#interface      eth0                    #default: eth0
interface       wlan1

opt     dns     8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
opt     subnet  255.255.255.0           #subnet to allow shared iface to send data to wlan0 gw
opt     router  192.168.2.254           #wlan1 - shared wifi iface - ip address
opt     lease 864000                    # 100 day lease

max_leases 64           #default: 254

remaining       yes             #default: yes

# The location of the leases file
#lease_file     /var/lib/misc/udhcpd.leases     #defualt: /var/lib/misc/udhcpd.leases

# The location of the pid file
pidfile         /var/run/udhcpd.pid     #default: /var/run/udhcpd.pid

# Static leases map
#w55eu laptop
static_lease b2:66:85:20:1e:32 192.168.2.1
#admin
static_lease 48:5a:3f:19:9d:63 192.168.2.4
```

I am completely lost as what is causing this: "Address already in use"

Any suggestions?

Comment: Not all dhcp servers have "dhcp" in their name.  `dnsmasq`, for example.  Check what processes are using the `domain` ports with `sudo ss -tlp` (for tcp/53) and `sudo ss -ulp` (for udp).